# Frequent disconnections in OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, networkmanager, openvpn

I'm suffering random disconnections with OpenVPN. I don't know much about the subject, maybe you can point me in the right direction? Here is the tail for `/var/log/messages`, it contains a `<warn>` and other relevant-looking lines:

```
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> Tunnel Device: tun0
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> IPv4 configuration:
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Internal Gateway: 10.8.0.65
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Internal Address: 10.8.0.66
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Internal Prefix: 32
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.8.0.65
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Static Route: 10.8.0.1/32   Next Hop: 10.8.0.1
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Forbid Default Route: no
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   Internal DNS: 10.8.0.1
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook nm-openvpn[5675]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info>   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Jul 15 21:27:58 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> No IPv6 configuration
Jul 15 21:27:59 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> VPN connection 'Some VPN' (IP Config Get) complete.
Jul 15 21:27:59 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> Policy set 'Some VPN' (tun0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jul 15 21:27:59 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Jul 15 21:27:59 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: started (4)
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopping (5)
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: Withdrawing workstation service for tun0.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.5 on em1.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface em1.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.5.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: Interface em1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface em1.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.5.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: New relevant interface em1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook avahi-daemon[910]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.5 on em1.IPv4.
Jul 15 21:28:44 notebook nm-openvpn[5675]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Jul 15 21:28:45 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> Policy set 'System em1' (em1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Jul 15 21:28:45 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Jul 15 21:28:45 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <warn> (5) failed to find interface name for index
Jul 15 21:28:45 notebook NetworkManager[907]: nm_system_iface_flush_routes: assertion `iface != NULL' failed
Jul 15 21:28:45 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <warn> (5) failed to find interface name for index
Jul 15 21:28:49 notebook NetworkManager[907]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

Comment: I've had the same problem with this for over a year. I've yet to figure out why it keeps disconnecting. I'm on Fedora 14 (which is dated) but a co-worker has Ubuntu 12.10 and it suffers the same behavior too. We've wondered if it's the server that's the issue but it's difficult to debug this issue.

Comment: @slm I've read reducing the MTU might help. Wanna try that? I'll do it too.

Comment: Yeah I tried that already. You should try it still, but it didn't change anything for me. Our behavior is that the connection will stay up for a few minutes and then disconnect.

Comment: What is the output of `grep openvpn /var/log/syslog |tail -n 100
`?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround create a script  that checks if openvpn is still running:

```
if ! pgrep "openvpn" > /dev/null; then 
  /usr/sbin/service openvpn restart
  echo "["$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"] openvpn restarted">> /var/log/openvpn.log
fi
```

and call chat script minutely in your crontab